# Array computation in javascript for add operation

Tags: javascript, arrays

we have an array, we have to find the sum of all the elements in the array.

```
let a = [1, 3, 2, 0];

console.log(a.add());  ==> 6
```

How to implement add function please can you help me?

Comment: Please [do basic research before asking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+sum+of+all+elements+in+array).

Comment: What is the hard part? Forking the prototype? Creating the sum? Something else?

Comment: Dupe hammer. OP wants to create a new function in Array prototype, not just sum all items in an array...

Answer (score 4):

There's no such function in `Array` prototype as `add`. You would have to create it.

**Note**: keep in mind that it's not recommended to modify the prototypes which may cause issues such as overwriting existing functions.

```js
const a = [1, 3, 2, 0];
Array.prototype.add = function() {
   return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

console.log(a.add())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let a = [1, 3, 2, 0];
var total = a.reduce((a,c) => a+c, 0);
console.log(total);
```